# InternalError: too much recursion <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am new to angularJS . I am stuck on above error.here is my index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <a href="table">click</a>

    <script src="./libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./libs/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

here is my script file

```
    var app=angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    console.log("i am routeprovider");
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl:"index.html"
    }).when('/table',{
        templateUrl:"..//views//firstview.html"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'google.com'
    })

}])
```

after running index.html on my local server i am getting following error in console

`InternalError: too much recursion
Stack trace:
[object Object]
 <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">`

see attached image.

[image]

please help me sort this issue .

Comment: Off-topic comment, but I am always amazed about how many people are currently starting to learn Angular 1 when Angular 2 came out in September 2016 and the current version is Angular 5, with 6 to come next month...

Comment: Please note that I am using angular 1.6.7 libs.

Comment: My point, precisely.

Comment: @JeremyThille, perhaps because people just want a nice and easy clientside framework, not a huge monolithic standard-breaking colossus  which changes every 6 month, and where you need to learn a completely new language and new patterns from scratch :)

Comment: @davidkonrad you are right .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you've set the `templateUrl` to index.html which is actually also your parent template.

When resolving the route '/' angular will inject the template index.html into the container `<div ng-view></div>`. The injected template also has the `ng-view` container. So angular will do this over and over again and is stuck in an endless recursion.

You can fix this by defining another partial view for this `templateUrl` e.g. defaultview.html.

Code

```
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    templateUrl:"..//views//defaultview.html"
}).when('/table',{
    templateUrl:"..//views//firstview.html"
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
})
```